# Error during select values from Data Frame using .format() in created function in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have function in Python Pandas like below:

```
def a():
    import pandas as pd

    ALL_MA_MR_MC = pd.read_csv("dane/clean_ALL_MA_MR_MC.csv", dtype = {"pesel_wsp": str, "pesel_ind" : str, "PESEL_MAIN" : str, "AI2key_logs" : str, "AI2KEY" : str, "activated" : str})

    segment = str(input())
    kategoria = str(input())
    
    x = df[(df["segment"] == "{}") & (df["logg"]== "{}")].format(segment, kategoria)
    
    return x
```

Nevertheless when I run this function and fulfill segment and kategoria parameters I have error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'format'
```

on below line:

```
----> 7     x = ALL_MA_MR_MC[(ALL_MA_MR_MC["SEGMENT"] == "{}") & (ALL_MA_MR_MC["logowanie"]== "{}")].format(segment, kategoria)
```

I am aware that I can use f-string like `f"{segment}"` and `f"{kategoria}"` nevertheless in this case I will have to fulfill parameters segment ad kategoria in quotation marks and I don't want that.

How to use .format() on line: `x = ALL_MA_MR_MC[(ALL_MA_MR_MC["SEGMENT"] == "{}") & (ALL_MA_MR_MC["logowanie"]== "{}")].format(segment, kategoria)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format method can only be applied to string, therefore you have to add it after the string you want to use it in.

```
x = df[(df["segment"] == "{}".format(segment)) & (df["logg"]== "{}".format(kategoria)
)]
```